# How to setImageResource of a dynamically declared ImageButtons?

Tags: android, imagebutton

I have some dynamically declared `ImageButtons`, these `ImageButtons` don't have ids' and they are declared in a `LinearLayout`, I want to create a method to change Images resources of these `ImageButtons` when called, and as I don't have a predefined ids' for these `ImageButtons` I'm using the function `getChildAt()` with the `LinearLayout`, but `getChildAt()` doesn't provide `setImageResource()`, it just provide `setBackgroundResource()` and this function doesn't make a replacement to the old Image and also doesn't fit at the old Image as it provides a **background** not an **Image Resource**, what can I do with that ?

this is my method code :

```
private void my_method(int drawable) {

        int count = Righter.getChildCount(); // Righter is the LinearLayout
        for (int i = 1; i < count; i++) {
            Righter.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(drawable); // here is where i change the background image 
            Righter.getChildAt(i).setClickable(true);
        }

    }
```

Comment: why your `ImageButtons` don't have `Ids`? set `Id` to each of them

Comment: have you tried `((ImageButton)Righter.getChildAt(i)).setBackgroundResource(drawable);`?

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan I can't, It's something related to the run-time of my application

Comment: you can set Id in run Time, `View.SetId();`

Comment: @SaifHamed I tried your way and it also works

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan I'm using the id and the tag for another purpose in my code :D, in general, the guys answers solved my problem

Comment: Ok,i glad, but you can use multiple tag for your require data and use id for id of your View

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan it's the first time i hear about multiple tag, I will give that a look, and thanks for your help

Comment: welcome. use `view.setTag(key, tag);` and get with `view.getTag(key);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getChildAt()` returns `View`. you need to typecast this `View` to `ImageButton` and call `setImageResource()` method...

```
    ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) linearLayout.getChildAt(0);
    imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.btnimage1);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
private void my_method(int drawable) {
   int count = Righter.getChildCount(); // Righter is the LinearLayout
   for (int i = 1; i < count; i++) {
       ((ImageButton)Righter.getChildAt(i)).setImageResource(R.drawable.btnimage1);
       Righter.getChildAt(i).setClickable(true);
   }
}
```

type cast you Righter.getChildAt(i) with `ImageButton`